# ObjC ARC: does a weak property's setter method run when the object is set to nil by ARC?

Tags: objective-c, properties, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

Really quick question (I could test it myself but not on a computer with Xcode):

If ARC sets a weak property to nil, will the property's setter run with the parameter being nil, or is the property setter bypassed in this case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. ARC doesn't set properties to nil. It will set the backing ivar to nil, but that doesn't run your setter.

Comment: Doing so would require calling out to arbitrary code while holding internal runtime locks.